# Setting sidebar width constraints in visionOS NavigationView

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationview, visionos

I'm aware it's possible to manipulate sidebar width for a `NavigationSplitView` like this.-

```
NavigationSplitView {
    Text("Sidebar")
        .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 100, ideal: 200, max: 300)
} content: {
    Text("Content")
        .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 100, ideal: 200, max: 300)
} detail: {
    Text("Detail")
}
```

But my main view includes a simple `NavigationView` (just a side bar and content), and it seems there's no api for specifying width in this case. Any known way to get the same effect in this scenario?

Comment: it isn’t a good idea to use NavigationView with visionOS, Apple deprecated it a couple of OSs ago and it is known to have a lot of bugs.

Comment: Thank you @loremipsum, wasn't aware of that. So I presume currently there's no official recommended way to get this kind of layout (single sidebar to the left and single content view)?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by that. If you are looking for a traditional Master/Detail that is what the NavigationSplitView does by default  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview you are depicting with this code a 3 column navigation.

Comment: Yep, the code is an example of a 3 column `NavigationSplitView`, but as stated in the question I'm working on a 2 column layout, which is what I get with the `NavigationView`.

Comment: If you look at the first set of code in the documentation you’ll see how to get a 2 column setup with NavigationSplitView

Comment: Oh I miss that one, please feel free to post an answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NavigationView` was deprecated a few OSs ago and should not be used in `visionOS` because it is known to have many bugs a limitations.

If you want to duplicate the 2 column setup you should migrate your code.

From

```
NavigationView { // This is deprecated.
    /* column 1 */
    /* column 2 */
}
```

To

```
NavigationSplitView {
    /* column 1 */
} detail: {
    /* column 2 */
}
```

Then you can use

```
.navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 100, ideal: 200, max: 300)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: Thank you @loremipsum, this works great, my only issue now is that I was using `searchable` to show a searchBar in the main content (right panel). Now it seems I can only show the search in the sidePanel unless I add the content object to get 3 columns.